# Почему не работает printf(), после ввода данных в функцию scanf_s?? Язык С, не С++

Tags: c

Вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char str[13];
scanf_s("%s", str);
printf("%s", str);
return 0;
}
```

вот вариант с амперсандом при вводе (думал может из-за него не работает как в других типах данных)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char str[13];
scanf_s("%s", &str);
printf("%s", str);
return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том что программа на некоторое время начинает грузиться ..ГРУЗИТЬСЯ!!!!!(банально с клавиатуры вывести на экран Hello World!), и после секунд 5 ничего не выводя консоль предлагает нажать любую клавишу для завершения.
Как заставить scanf() вводить строки без сбоев????

Comment: scanf_s("%s", str, sizeof(str));

Comment: спасибо большое, заработало )) но если не затруднит не объясните почему не работало и зачем в этой конструкции нужен sizeof()?

Comment: ф-ия с приставкой '_s' указывает на то, что она безопасна (safe). И для таких ф-ий нужно указывать размер буфера.

Comment: спасибо вам большое, я вчера весь день убил на то чтобы найти ответ на этот вопрос))

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman, бросайте винду, все сразу упростится